# How do you set node configurations in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a wrapper cookbook that installs elasticsearch.

The cookbook supports dynamic config files by using the following syntax:

```
node.elasticsearch[:custom_config]
```

https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/f7fb420a8641cbfa3e76acd64714dcc16ac6e274/templates/default/elasticsearch.yml.erb#L9-L16

When I try and implement this in my wrapper cookbook, I get the following error:

```
   12>> node[:elasticsearch][:custom_config] = {'indices.breaker.fielddata.limit' => '75%'}
        13:  node[:elasticsearch][:custom_config] = {'indices.fielddata.cache.size' => '65%'}
        14:  
        15:  
        16:  
        17:  # Work around for issue when no ssl certs are present
        18:  # https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/commit/7bdaffc0a1b8e2ae17dc9ab961a468daf9825b98
        19:  # normal[:elasticsearch][:nginx][:ssl][:cert_file] = nil
        20:  # normal[:elasticsearch][:nginx][:ssl][:key_file] = nil
        21:  


       Running handlers:

       Running handlers complete

       [2015-05-01T17:10:42+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.969790492 seconds
       [2015-05-01T17:10:42+00:00] ERROR: Node attributes are read-only when you do not specify which precedence level to set. To set an attribute use code like `node.default["key"] = "value"'
       [2015-05-01T17:10:42+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

From my research, it appears that on chef 11 and newer, you must specify your scope like so:

```
node.set[:elasticsearch][:custom_config] { 'foo' => 'bar' }
node.default[:elasticsearch][:custom_config] { 'foo' => 'bar' }
```

Unfortunately using those syntaxes in my default.rb does not work, since foo and bar never appear in my config.

What is the proper way to override a node value in a wrapper cookbook?

**Update**

I've also tried the following syntax with no luck.

```
default['elasticsearch']['custom_config'] = {
  'indices.breaker.fielddata.limit' => '75%',
  'indices.fielddata.cache.size' => '65%'
}
```

The code that implements this is located here:

https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/1e48dc99816e09ac96e2e850e70768fab6c82b89/templates/default/elasticsearch.yml.erb#L161-L163

**Update 2 **

It appears that my elasticsearch.yaml is different than the one on github

I noticed that mine has a row #####Security#### whereas github doesn't. Also github has #####custom#### whereas mine doesn't. Both are version 0.3.13 of the cookbook.

http://pastebin.com/1nCjJY1d
https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/v0.3.13/templates/default/elasticsearch.yml.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was working, however there are 2 elasticsearch files.

```
/usr/local/elasticsearch/conf/elasticsearch.yml
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

The first one is not used, but the second one was updated.

[Related github issue](https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch/pull/314#event-346694621)